# Git clean filter not executed on Windows

Tags: git, filter

I want to create a custom clean/smudge filter on Windows 7.

This is the filter setup in the local config file:

```
[filter "insertSha"]
    smudge = cat
    clean = 'D:/clean.exe'
```

This is the content of my .gitattributes file:

```
 *.sha.cs    insertSha
```

The file I'm interested in seams to meat the filter criteria:

```
$ git check-attr -a myFile.sha.cs
myFile.sha.cs: insertSha: set
```

The executable (clean.exe) is not called since for tracing purpose I create a file at a known place each time the program is executed.

I also tried to put the executable in other places but it doesn't work either.

All examples I found so far for clean/smudge filters only involve calling `sed` or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps your `.gitattributes` should say:

```
*.sha.cs filter=insertSha
```

I think `git` effectively ignores unknown attributes for the sake of future portability (introduction of new attributes in new versions of `git`), so it sees your `insertSha` and doesn't understand it as an attribute it knows about, and then promptly ignores it...

Comment: This did it. It's funny, because this is the form I tried first. Must have been another reason why it didn't work then.